# Display posts without offset

Tags: php, wordpress

So I was having trouble with pagination and offset together then I decided to use some rules to display the posts and it worked. The problem here is because I need to display the posts in 3 different ways, when I was using offset I could set in each WP_query the number of the post that I dind't want to display, with the if is much easier but I'm stuck here:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">       
    <?php
    $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;  
    $query = new WP_Query(array('posts_per_page'=> 8, 'paged' => $paged));
    if($query->have_posts()):
      while($query->have_posts()):
        $query->the_post();
        $p++;
        if($p==1 && $p%2==1):
    ?>
    <!-- Post here -->
 </div>
</div>
  <section id="lasted-posts">
    <div class="row" >
        ~ here ~
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12">
         <!-- Another post here -->
       </div>
    </div> 
   <div class="row"> 
   ~ here ~
     <?php elseif ($p%2==0): ?>
      <div class="col-md-4">
             <!-- Normal post here -->                   
      </div>              
   <?php endif; endwhile; endif;   wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
 </div>
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div>
        <?php wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $query ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_pagination( array( 'query' => $query ) ); ?>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

(edit)
I was reading the wordpress documentation because I was using the offset and  having trouble with the pagination, when the pagination "worked" it was showing the same posts from the front page. I read a lot of issues here and decided to not use offset, but to do this I changed the whole code. With the offset I was using 3 WP_query with the numbers of posts to show for that specific style, but now I know how to display only 2 different posts style with:

```html
<?php
$p++;
    if($p==1 && $p%2==1) :  
?> do something
        and   
<?php 
  elseif ($p%2==0): 
?>
```

I tried with 3 posts and didn't worked. Any ideas ?
I know its just logic problem, I tried somethings but didn't worked (a newbie with wordpress). What I should put where is ~ here ~ to display the posts in 3 different ways ?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Question: which "different ways"? You'll need to explain in detail what it is you're trying to do so we can help you out. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: Ty :) Just visual HTML & CSS nothing related with category e etc. Like this https://prnt.sc/m32bl5

Comment: I was reading the wordpress documentation because I was using the offset and  having trouble with the pagination, when the pagination "worked" it was showing the same posts from the front page. I read a lot of issues here and decided to not use offset, but to do this I changed the whole code. With the offset I was using 3 WP_query with the numbers of posts to show for that specific style, but now I know how to display only 2 different posts style with:  $p++;
        if($p==1 && $p%2==1) :  and   elseif ($p%2==0):